# Crash dump issue while uploading .csv coordinates as vector in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinates, csv, minidump

I am using QGIS 2.18 in Windows.

I want to show some coordinates in a map, for which I am uploading a .csv file, but it shows a crash dump every time with error "CRS was not defined". I have attached the image. Is there any solution please?

[image]

Comment: Try changing your project CRS to ESPG:4326 because that is the coordinate system your lat and longs are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should be reported at http://issues.qgis.org, with the CSV attached.